# require_once(PHP/CodeCoverage/Filter.php): failed to open stream

Tags: php, symfony, testing, phpunit, composer-php

I am trying to get familiar with testing (unit, functional) under Symfony 2.3.24/Windows7/PHP 5.4.7.

It seems PHPUnit is installed correctly (via Composer), but when I run a `phpunit -c app/` command I get the following error:

```
Warning: require_once(PHP/CodeCoverage/Filter.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\php\phpunit on line 38

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHP/CodeCoverage/Filter.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\php\phpunit on line 38
```

I googled for the issue to no avail. I additionnaly found in the official PHPUnit website that `The code coverage report feature requires the Xdebug (2.1.3 or later) and tokenizer extensions`.

What do you think about all this? your help is much appreciated.

Comment: check `php -i` (or `phpinfo()` output). Are the extensions mentioned on PHPUnit installed? (Xdebug and tokenized), and are they enabled?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem, thank you first. phpinfo() page tells that Tokenizer support is enabled. But for Xdebug, I find no info on the page. I checked symfony profiler page and Xdebug is disabled. Do I need to uncomment the specific lines in php.ini? Note that there is no line in phpinfo for PHPUnit. Should it exist?

Comment: I suspect you'll have to install Xdebug yourself (google will tell you how)

Comment: You are right, I was thinking that Xdebug is enabled after uncommenting the specific lines on php.ini, but it was not sufficient since I need also to change value of `xdebug.remote_enable` to 1. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In current versions of PHPUnit the `phpunit` script does not include `PHP/CodeCoverage/Filter.php` directly. It appears you are using an outdated version of PHPUnit and/or have a mixup of Composer/PEAR installations.

Please follow the instructions on https://phpunit.de/getting-started.html to properly install PHPUnit. And http://thephp.cc/news/2015/01/phpunit-migration-from-pear-to-phar explains how to migrate from a PEAR-based installation to Composer or PHAR.